# How To Prevent CKEditor Hide Android Keyboard On Press Enter Key

Tags: android, ckeditor, android-softkeyboard

I am having trouble using CKEditor.  Every time I press the enter key on Android it closes the keyboard.  I have to press / click the editor again to open the keyboard.  Can this be prevented?

Please help.  I've been looking for an answer everywhere, I can't find the answer.  Thank you.

I tried on this demo page the results were the same.
https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/demo/

Answer (score 0):

This problem has already been reported on the official github website at the following link https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/issues/4252

And they come to the conclusion that it is a browser error.